# DH parameters for lynx robot

Tags: forward-kinematics, dh-parameters

Can anyone help me out with DH parameters and axis placement for below kinematic chain?[image: below is the lynx robot kinematic chain]

[image: solved dh parameters]

Comment: I'll soon post my axis placement and DH parameters(which are wrong).Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, Vishal. Please do post the work that you've done so far. Does the drawing you posted show the robot with all joints at their zero position? You don't have any x or y axes drawn on the figure, except the base and end effector, and the joint for $\theta_5$ isn't dimensioned.

Comment: Hi there,above shown is the question that i was given. I'm working on creating axis and parameters. Previously done work was horribly wrong so resisted myself from posting it.I'll post a respectable copy of work so that i can get some inputs.

Comment: hi, please find attached uploaded image in which i have tried to solve for dh parameters. the first image shows the robot in zero pose. i request you all to correct me wherever i have gone wrong from frame assignment to parameters values. thanks in advanced.